# Can't get keys from a hashmap in guestbook app

Tags: clojure, luminus

I'm playing with the luminus guestbook app. 
I added some logging statements in `g.test.db.core.clj` to look at the keys of the data structures. Look at "Expected Keys" and "Actual Keys" below.

```
(deftest test-messages
  (jdbc/with-db-transaction [t-conn db/conn]
                            (jdbc/db-set-rollback-only! t-conn)
                            (let [timestamp (java.util.Date.)]
                              (is (= 1 (db/save-message!
                                         {:name      "Bobby"
                                          :message   "Hello World!"
                                          :timestamp timestamp}
                                         {:connection t-conn})))
                              (let [actual (-> (db/get-messages {} {:connection t-conn}))
                                    expected {:name      "Bobby"
                                              :message   "Hello World!"
                                              :timestamp timestamp}]
                                (log/info "Expected Keys")
                                (pprint (keys expected))
                                (log/info "Actual Keys")
                                (pprint (keys actual))  ;;<--this is the problem
                                (is (= actual
                                       expected))))))
```

**The "Expected Keys" print fine, but I get a runtime exception for "Actual Keys":**

> [2017-03-04 14:31:28,076]Expected Keys
>   (:name :message :timestamp)
>
> [2017-03-04 14:31:28,089]Actual Keys
>
> lein test :only guestbook.test.db.core/test-messages
>
> ERROR in (test-messages) (:) Uncaught exception, not in assertion.
>   expected: nil   actual: java.lang.ClassCastException: null  at [empty
>   stack trace]
>
> lein test guestbook.test.handler

However, if I do this:
`(pprint actual)`
I get what I want:

```
({:id 35,
  :name "Bobby",
  :message "Hello World!",
  :timestamp #inst "2017-03-04T04:31:01.030000000-00:00"})
```

**What is going on? Why can't I print the keys from the data structure returned from the database?**

Comment: Do you really want to say `(-> (db/get-messages {} {:connection t-conn}))`?  That seems like it may be a mis-type, since I can't think of another reason you'd use the thread macro with a single expression.

Comment: Add the stack trace.

Comment: @Josh I can't answer that. It was there when I clone the repo.

Comment: @FrankHenard This was as much of a stacktrace as I get: "null at [empty stack trace]" See above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like actual is a list and not a map. Try `(-> actual first keys pprint)`

Comment: That's exactly right. How do you figure it out? Could you tell from the log or did you have to clone the project and try it out?

Comment: Glad it worked!  I saw the open paren `(` in front of the map in the results from your `(pprint actual)`.  I have also done some db work in Clojure, so I probably have encountered that issue before.